# Octave Error: imread cannot find image.jpg

Tags: image, image-processing, octave

I've googled this error, that is received through both octave console and xoctave, and tried the suggestions to include the `cd` command followed by setting the `IMAGE_PATH` both to the same image path.

After trying the above suggestion, the imread still doesn't work emitting the same error; the path where the image exists is the very same as that of xoctave's default workspace. I've already went through Xoctave's `options>console> Where is Octave` to insert the correct directory to octave.exe and then saved and reopened xoctave.

The error is:

```
error: imread: cannot find image.jpg 
error: called from: 
error:      C:\octave\3.2.4.gcc-4.4.O\share\octave\3.2.4\m\image\imread.m at 1ine 53, column 5
```

---

On octave installation, I've chosen the default installation settings (as partly seen below), as well as all the "Octave Forge" packages ("image" inclusive). I've then installed and extracted the image processing toolbox found [here](http://octave.sourceforge.net/image/index.html).

[image]

The strange thing is that I've had the same imread error on a different computer (running windows XP) that was resolved as soon as I've changed directory (cd) and set IMAGE_PATH to the required workspace. Also, on using `ls` to list the directory's contents, the image is found within as expected.

I'm using Octave 3.2.4 and Xoctave 0.9.79 beta; running on Windows 7 64-bit.

Comment: That may be a problem with Xoctave. Can you replicate the problem if you try it from the Octave prompt without Xoctave? Also, why don't you update Octave? 3.2.4 is quite old. There have 2 releases since (and 8 minor releases with 3.6.4 alsmot out).

Comment: Thank you for your comment.   
Yes, the problem occurs also with Octave prompt. Actually I was reading a tutorial and downloaded the version accordingly. I noticed it's not quite straightforward to find a pre-compiled version of  the latest Octave (I've installed Octave 3.2.4 from a .exe); I couldn't find in my search so far except source files [here](ftp://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/octave).

Comment: see the octave wiki for instructions (it's not completely up to date but is very very close) http://wiki.octave.org/Octave_for_Windows and Octave Forge for the binaries http://octave.sourceforge.net/ (there's a button there for windows installers)

Comment: Yes, I've looked into these, but haven't quite went into the wiki instructions. I should give it another try. Thanks a lot for your help.